# How do I handle json data sent as an HTTP Post to a cakephp app?

Tags: cakephp

If I'm being sent an HTTP Post where the body of the http request is just a UTF8 encoded string, how do I access that data in my cakephp controller? It appears that $this->params only contains the following:

```
{
    "pass":[],
    "named":[],
    "controller":"users",
    "action":"checkin",
    "plugin":null,
    "url":{
        "ext":"json",
        "url":"users\/checkin.json"
    },
    "form":[],
    "isAjax":false
}
```

The data being posted looks something like this:

```
{
    "sessionkey":"somecrazykey",
    "longitude":"-111.12345",
    "latitude":"33.12345",
    "reqtype":"checkin",
    "location":"the mall",
    "public":"true"
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if($this->RequestHandler->requestedWith('json')) {
    if(function_exists('json_decode')) {
        $jsonData = json_decode(utf8_encode(trim(file_get_contents('php://input'))), true);
    }

    if(!is_null($jsonData) and $jsonData !== false) {
        $this->data = $jsonData;
    }
}
```

This is a codesnippet which was proposed to be in the core, see https://trac.cakephp.org/ticket/6125. Maybe it's what you're looking for.

-- Bjorn

Comment: Bjorn,
Thanks for the reply. It turns out that my problem wasn't on the cake side of things, it was the client POSTing the data. It wasn't actually arriving at the server.

Thanks for your help though!
Cameron

Answer (score 6):

You can use these simplest way :

```
$data = $this->request->input ( 'json_decode', true) ;
```

Comment: I think this is a better solution that @Bjorn's. Simple and uses the CakePHP codebase.