# XCode (iPhone) posting a JSON object to a cakePHP server?

Tags: xcode, cakephp

I've got cakePHP running on my server.  I'm trying to have my iPhone App post a JSON object to the server, then have the server echo it back.  (Keeping it simple for now.)  I've accessed the server plenty with normal URLs and gotten views back including JSON objects.  This is my first attempt at posting JSON to the server.  But it doesn't work.  It always echos a null back.

**In my iPhone App**

```
NSDictionary* myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:dictObjects forKeys:dictKeys];

NSData* jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myDict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];

NSData *requestData;

// I've tried it both ways with this stringified or not
/*
NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:jsonObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:jsonString length:[jsonString length]];
*/
requestData = [NSData dataWithData:jsonObject];

urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myServer.com/json_tests/echo_json"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:requestData];
[urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[urlRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[urlRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[jsonObject length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
currentConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
```

**My CakePHP Server**

This is in my controller file

```
public function echo_json() {
   $rawData = $this->params['form'];
   $decodedData = json_decode($rawData);

   $this->layout = 'json';
   $this->set(compact('rawData', 'decodedData'));
}
```

My view has ... `echo $rawData;  echo json_encode($decodedData);`

But you know raw html source code doesn't get displayed here.

Comment: H2C03, I've accepted every answer that I was able to verify myself.  Do you know the answer to this question?  From your profile, you look like a wizard at this.  If you answer I'll get my SW working and accept ASAP.  Thx,  Joe

Comment: So are you sure the data doesn't get POSTed to tge server? What if you try using a different method for posting? For example, does the problem still exist if you use libcurl instead of the NSURL API?

Comment: Well that's just it.  I can't tell who is the culprit.  Did my iPhone not send it correctly?  Or did my server not fetch it correctly?  Would $this->params['form'] do it?  I know even less about curl than I know about NSURL.  At least I've used NSURL to do regular (non-post) URL accesses before.

Comment: I don't know CakePHP. What if you echo back your $_POST variable?

Comment: H2CO3 is there any way for us to exchange contact info without posting it for everyone to see here?  I'm not in any of the social networks that you have in your profile.  I simply have e-mail.

Comment: OK I got something working.  It is basically Bjorn's answer from http://stackoverflow.com/q/1766621/883354 minus that first 'if' statement.  So I use the file_get_contents('php://input') to get the json object.  And I didn't have to "stringify" the json object before I sent it in the XCode app.